How to use Geometry Nodes to transfer normal attributes from a Mesh object to a geometry-node based fur system?
Pretty much that. How do I use Geometry Nodes to transfer normal attributes from a Mesh object to a geometry-node based fur system? I need to do this to achieve a stylized hair shader for geometry hair curves. But I can't seem to get it to work...

This is way too vague.... can you be more specific? Do you mean "normal direction"? Where do you want it? How does the mesh relate to the fur system?

Best way is to show you. I want to achieve this look with shading of hair curves: https://i.postimg.cc/PJPLMbyB/fur.png
To do that, I need to copy the normals of the mesh to the curves.
